# why trim the random proportion when randomly generate a location in a given map?

Tags: julia

I was reading a piece of code to generate a random location in a given map. I understand the main idea. However, I was confused a bit as the random proportion is trimmed before applied to the map coordinates to get the coordinates of the random location.

```
function randLocation(map::Map; trim::Float = 0.0, rng::AbstractRNG = Base.GLOBAL_RNG)
    @assert(trim >= 0 && trim <= 1)
    r = rand(rng, 2) .* (1-trim) + trim/2
    location = Location()
    location.x = map.xMin + map.xRange * r[1]
    location.y = map.yMin + map.yRange * r[2]
    return location
end
```

Comment: I will delete this question after two days, as I really start to think that it's not necessary to trim the proportion.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the "map" here has the dimensions of the probably small boundaries of a place defined by GPS or similar hardware. The trim variable appears to be used to decrease the amount of fuzzing that is done. The effect would be like opening and closing the spot on a screen with a focusing lens.

Such a random value may be used to "fuzz" the map's location, for privacy purposes. If there are no concerns such as the location being private and the application making this public, this fuzzing data could be removed.